# Agreement at installation time

Tags: android

I want to specify the Agreement when user installs the app.I meant when user set up for permissions needed just after that I want Agreement.I dont want to include extra activity in my app.Please help me.I tried to google but I found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to specify the Agreement when user installs the app

You are welcome to display a license agreement when the user launches your app for the first time. A typical approach for this is to use `SharedPreferences` to track whether the user has agreed to the license agreement, showing the agreement if necessary.

> I meant when user set up for permissions needed just after that I want Agreement

You are welcome to get a job at Google, join the team that maintains the Play Store, and augment the Play Store to have it present a license agreement as part of the installation process.

Then, you can get a job at Amazon and repeat the modifications, this time for the Amazon AppStore for Android.

Then, you can get a job at BlackBerry and repeat the modifications, this time for BlackBerry World. These modifications may also be required for other distribution channels, where the distribution channel is the primary one on the device, and so the presentation of permissions is handled by the channel.

Then, you can return to a job at Google and modify Android to present a license agreement after presenting the permissions, for cases where the app is installed via other means (e.g., downloading from a Web site). Then, you will need to wait for this version of Android to become dominant in the ecosystem, which may take a few years.

Then, you will be able to show your license agreement just after the presentation of permissions.

It would be far simpler for you to display your license agreement when the user launches your app for the first time.

> I dont want to include extra activity in my app.

You are welcome to modify your existing launcher activity to handle the license agreement for the on-first-launch scenario, such as via a fragment.

Comment: Thank you sir :) 
By the way I just wanted to know if it was possible or not.May be it was possible then I could implement it otherwise I already made it with SharedPrefs.Your essay was great! Thank you again :p

Comment: @JustinJames: "By the way I just wanted to know if it was possible or not" -- in future Stack Overflow questions, you might want to mention that. As it stands, your question is more of a demand ("I want X. I do not want Y."). I elected to explain the only real way of meeting the demand. And, in truth, it *would* be really useful for a standard way to present a license agreement, one that could be handled by distribution channels and/or Android itself. However, right now, we have to handle it ourselves.

Comment: This is possibly my favourite ever answer.